# Hint for SQL Query Joined tables with million records

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions, hint

I have below query that is taking on an average more than 5 seconds to fetch the data in a transaction that is triggered in-numerous times via application. I am looking for a hint that can possibly help me reduce the time taken for this query everytime its been fired. My conditions are that I cannot add any indexes or change any settings of application for this query. Hence oracle hints or changing the structure of the query is the only choice I have. Please find below my query.

```
SELECT  SUM(c.cash_flow_amount) FROM  CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL a ,CM_CONTRACT b,CM_CONTRACT_CASHFLOW c
                                   WHERE a.country_code         = Ip_country_code
                                   AND   a.company_code         = ip_company_code
                                   AND   a.dealer_bp_id         = ip_bp_id
                                   AND   a.contract_start_date >= ip_start_date
                                   AND   a.contract_start_date <= ip_end_date
                                   AND   a.version_number       = b.current_version
                                   AND   a.status_code          IN ('00','10')
                                   AND   a.country_code         = b.country_code
                                   AND   a.company_code         = b.company_code
                                   AND   a.contract_number      = b.contract_number 
                                   AND   a.country_code         = c.country_code
                                   AND   a.company_code         = c.company_code
                                   AND   a.contract_number      = c.contract_number
                                   AND   a.version_number       = c.version_number
                                   AND   c.cash_flow_type_code IN ('07','13');
```

The things to know about the tables are that they are all transactional tables and the data of this table keeps changing everyday. They have records in 1 lacs to 10 lacs in numbers.
This is the explain plan currently on the query:

Operation   Object Name Rows    Bytes   Cost    Object Node In/Out  PStart  PStop

```
SELECT STATEMENT Hint=RULE                               
  SORT AGGREGATE                                 
    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID CM_CONTRACT_CASHFLOW                             
      NESTED LOOPS                               
        NESTED LOOPS                                 
          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL                           
            INDEX RANGE SCAN    XIF760CT_CONTRACT_DETAIL                             
          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   CM_CONTRACT                          
            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   XPKCM_CONTRACT                           
        INDEX RANGE SCAN    XPKCM_CONTRACT_CASHFLOW                          

Indexes on CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL:
XPKCM_CONTRACT_DETAIL is a composite unique index on country_code, company_code, contract_number and version_number
XIF760CT_CONTRACT_DETAIL is a non unique index on dealer_bp_id

Indexes on CM_CONTRACT:
XPKCM_CONTRACT is a composite unique index on country_code, company_code, contract_number

Indexes on CM_CONTRACT_CASHFLOW:
XPKCM_CONTRACT_CASHFLOW is a composite unique index on country_code, company_code, contract_number and version_number,supply_sequence_number, cash_flow_type_code,payment_date.
```

Could you please help better this query? Please let me know if anything else about the tables is required on this. Stats are not gathered on this tables either.

Comment: *"My conditions are that I cannot add any indexes [...] for this query"* - Why? That's what indexes are for. Also, any particulare reason to use these old style joins instead of `inner join`?

Comment: How big are the tables that you're joining?  Have you tried the HASH hint to prevent nested loops?  When's the last time the tables were analyzed?

Comment: I think the tables have all indexes there should be and since these tables are used all over the application for multipurposes, any advices to add indexes would not be welcome. Which HASH hint are you referring to? Use_hash? That hint works better if one of the table has fewer records. Here all tables have thousands of hundreds of records. I would have to check when was the last time table were analysed with DBA's. Will get that info.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your query plan says HINT=RULE. Why is that? Is this the standard setting in your dbms? Why not make use of the optimizer? You can use `/*+CHOOSE*/` for that. This may be all that's needed. (Why are there no Stats on the tables, though?)</strike>

EDIT: The above was nonsense. By not gathering any statistics you prevent the optimizer from doing its work. It will always fall back to the good old rules, because it has no basis to calculate costs on and find a better plan. It is strange to see that you voluntarily keep the dbms from getting your queries fast. You can use hints in your queries of course, but be careful always to check and alter them when table data changes significantly. Better gather statistics and have the optimizer doing this work. As to useful hints:

My feeling says: With that many criteria on CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL this should be the driving table. You can force that with `/*+LEADING(a)*/`. Maybe even use a full table scan on that table `/*+FULL(a)*/`, which you can still speed up with parallel execution: `/*+PARALLEL(a,4)*/`.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Its a standard setting I suppose since I see that in all the plans? is there any command that I can run to check if thats the case?

Comment: I tried all the hints suggested and I see that FULL SCAN is actually increasing the cost of the query. With LEADING Hint there was no change in the explain plan. I mean it remained same. Is there anything I can do about dealer_bp_id column on CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL TABLE? I have a feeling that it is causing the cost of the query. Is the query good enough structure wise?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I've just never seen the dbms chose the RULE plan. By not gathering any statistics you prevent the optimizer from doing its work. It doesn't know, if certain criteria will get 1% of the table data or 99%. So it falls back to using old rules. Whatever COST you see, don't believe it! The optimizer has (almost) no basis for calculationg costs. So try your query with the FULL hint and measure time instead.

Comment: As to LEADING: This is strange. I didn't expect the optimizer to be so stubborn, especially when it has no stats to argue against it :-) You can try `/*+ORDERED*/` instead. In your query it does more or less the same thing; it starts with CM_CONTRACT_DETAIL. But again: Why are there no statistics? Thus you tell the dbms: "I know, you want to get my queries fast, but I won't let you. Nah nah nah nah nah!"

Comment: As to the query's structure: It is good. Straight forward. Well, the query is simple enough :-) Only, why are you using the old comma-separated join syntax that was replaced in standard SQL more than twenty years ago? Are you using a very old Oracle version?

Comment: I have been told by my DBA team that In our side, oracle environments are using rule based optimizer…not cost based.
Stats would have little effect in such a scenario.

Comment: Oracle itself favors the cost-based optimizer and as of Oracle 10g the rule-based optimizer is obsolete and no longer supported. The reason for this is that the cost-based optimizer is better :-) So either you have a very, very old Oracle version or your DBAs deliberately run the dbms in slow mode, so to say.

Comment: Have you run the query with FULL or even PARALLEL hint? As mentioned: Without stats the COSTS mean quite nothing. You must run the query to see whether it is faster or not.

Comment: I just tried all hints suggested and captured the execution time & I must say /*+PARALLEL(a,4)*/ surprised me. It is taking around 3 secs to fetch the data where as the original query is taking around 12 secs in DEV ENV. Although /*+ index(A XIF760CT_CONTRACT_DETAIL)*/ is also giving me a good execution time of 3.5 seconds approx. My doubt is how come this index hint is helping the query to run better compare to the original query which was taking long time even though this index was used in the explain plan.? Does Parallel hint have any sideaffects of being used as a hint?

Comment: When you query data and then query it again, the second query will be fast, because some data will still be in cache. So it is very difficult to compare different hints, because the first query will usually be slow and all following will benefit from data being in memory already. So always execute the queries several times to get an idea of their avarage process time.

Comment: Nope, I flushed shared_pool and buffer_cache before running each query. 

alter system flush buffer_cache;

alter system flush shared_pool; Is this not enough? Now coming back to my query on hint. How is that hint /*+ index(A XIF760CT_CONTRACT_DETAIL)*/  doing a better job when used a hint?

Comment: Sorry to say, I have no idea.

Comment: Thats okay. Thank you for your help Thorsten :) I learned a thing or two about hints now :)